# I want to build a media server. media only. is this possible with ubuntu?

Tags: server

I just completed machine re purposing number 3. 
We want to build a media server for music, pictures, and video.
Everything must come from used sources, or be free.
How do I configure a server to run in this environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very possible. Look into [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) and/or [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/).

Answer (score 0):

To bring up another option...
I use [Plex Media Server](http://plex.tv/downloads). I can then access my media on my Roku set-top box and other devices. I also have a free myPlex account which gives me a media queue. I have a bookmarklet I click when watching a YouTube or Dailymotion video for instance. It places it on queue, making it accessible on my devices. Usually have to forward a port on the router to link to myPlex though, as the Plex server and myPlex need to communicate back and forth.

http://plex.tv

Hope this helps.